# Role of 1 in homogeneous transformation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a 4x4 homogeneous transformation matrix that performs any useful transformation on point X to produce a transformed point X':

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a & b & c & 0 \\
e & f & g & 0 \\
i & j & k & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Could anybody please enlighten me what role does 1 (at 4,4) play?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having a great deal of trouble understanding what it is that you're asking. What are the letters? What is a "useful" transformation? Could you please clarify your question or provide some context?

Comment: @TomOldfield: To be specific, let us consider a position vector X:=[3 2 1 1] and translate it by -1,-1,-1 in x,y and z respectively. Now, the transformation matrix T would be [1 0 0 -1|0 1 0 -1|0 0 1 -1|0 0 0 1]. We would obtain X':=T*X. Why is it necessary to write 1 at (4,4) in T?

Comment: @matlunix if the last row of $T$ is anything except $(0, 0, 0, 1)$, then $T$ might not preserve the property that the last element of $X$ is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way of representing a $n$-dimensional vector as a $(n+1)$-dimensional vector. We represent the vector $(x,y,z)$ as

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z \\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

why would we do this? Observe that if we left-multiply the above vector by the matrix,

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & \Delta x \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \Delta y \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \Delta z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z \\
1
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x + \Delta x\\
y + \Delta y\\
z + \Delta z\\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

we get a representation of the original vector translated by $(\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta z)$. Hence we can represent a translation as a matrix multiplication.

The matrix in your question represents a linear transformation of $(x,y,z)$.

For more, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations

Comment: :Thanks. So, 1 acts as a global scale in the transformation matrix. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "1 acts as a scale".

Comment: In the transformation matrix mentioned above, if 1 is replaced by a scaling factor s (s not equal to 0), the original vector gets translated by (s.Δx,s.Δy,s.Δz). This can be interpreted as a global scale.

Comment: If 1 is replaced by $s$, the last row of $Tx$ will be $s$, but our convention is that a "represented vector" has 1 as its last element. Btw, it is a bit distracting to read what you write if you don't use latex.